# Machine Learning re-training model with predictions

Tags: machine-learning

I have a model which uses the data from all the previous days to make a prediction for today. (use 0:t-1 data to predict t data)

Now i want to extend this model to make predictions for next n days. However instead of using just 0:t-1 data for predictions for t, t+1, t+2 and so on; i would also like to use the prediction made for t, t+1, and so on to re-train the model and make predictions for t+1, t+2 and so on respectively.

so for prediction for t: use 0:t-1 data

for prediction for t+1: use 0:t-1 data + prediction for t above.

for prediction for t+2: use 0:t-1 data + prediction for t above + prediction for t+1 above

Is this an accepted practice in the ML community? 
What is the best method to do so?

My naive solution: I train using t-1 data. Make prediction for t. Re-train with t-1 + t prediction. Make prediction for t+1. and so on.

The issue i face: Training the model takes some time (~1.5-2 mins) and repeating the process for each day is seemingly counter-intuitive. When i run it for 100 days to predict, it takes around 3 hours.

Comment: There are multiple ways you could handle that but it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. As soon as you retrain with your second test data point, the result of the first test data point is no longer valid. You are essentially abusing the whole point of having test data. Considering how small the test set is, why not just predict with the entire test data set, then retrain with the whole set?

Comment: apologies for the mistake.. i understand what you are saying.. i will rephrase the question..

Comment: i have rephrased the question.. can you please take a look now? and guide me?

Comment: What kind of model are you using?

Comment: i am using a neural network.

Comment: also it is a classification problem that i am trying to solve here.

Comment: Are you manually labeling the classes each day for the new data?

Comment: No.. it is an automated process..

Comment: So a little more clarification.. each day a script runs which trains the model and spews out a prediction.. this prediction is then stored in a database and used in down-stream systems.. however there is a real life event which happens (eg rain / no rain) and this event is the correct label..

Comment: Now when the script runs the next day, i will use the correct label due to real life event and not my prediction.. the problem i am facing is generalising the model to predict for the next n days and not just 1 day..

Comment: Through empirical observation, i have noticed that there is a correlation between t and t-1 data.. if i predict for n days, i lose this correlation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question (even including your comments) is rather vague since it doesn't describe the input data to your model. There is also ambiguity when you say "use prediction x" because "use" could mean use as training data or use as an input to your trained model.

You should not use prediction data to retrain your model. If your model is not perfect (if it were, there would be no reason to retrain) you will be creating an incestuous model that is trained on its own outputs and will be using it's own errors as "truth" labels.

In your comment, you mentioned that there is a "real life event" that provides a correct (truth) label. It is certainly acceptable to retrain your model when you receive new truth data.

There are numerous way you can deal with your processing issues. The best way will depend on the details of your model but here are some options to consider in general:

- Simply wait for `N` days until you retrain the model.
- Only retrain the model when it makes an incorrect prediction.
- Limit the amount of data used for retraining (e.g., only use the
  `M` most-recent days of data).

With regard to "using" predictions and/or new truth data, that could be done without retraining your entire model by using a model that takes sequences of `N` days of data as input. So for example, you could used days `t-N-1:t-1` to predict day `t`. Then - without retraining the model - use days `t-N:t` to predict day `t+1`. That could be done with either predictions or new truth values. The specifics of how large `N` should be would depend on the details of your model and input data (e.g., does it consider date / seasonal variability).

Comment: by 'use' i meant use as training data, and i think i am clear about the negative consequences of the same.. thank you! i am getting highly drawn to "Only retrain the model when it makes an incorrect prediction." and not fix the re-training to a set interval of time (1 day, 1 week, etc.) as there is no perceptible pattern in the feature vectors that can help me fix the retrain interval with much confidence.

Comment: selecting this as the answer, as i decided to retrain the model when an incorrect prediction is made.

Answer (score 1):

- Okay, so we have the labelled data for `t-1` days, and we want to predict the results for let's say next `n` days.
- As it is not mentioned in the question that what are the input features that we are taking corresponding to each day, I would assume that the feature-vectors corresponding to different days are independent of each other. Saying that, we have `t-1` independent training data-points, and using those, we want to predict the output for new `n` data-points.
- Let us first discuss the approach suggested in the question and then let's discuss a possible better solution according to me.
- So, in the question, the OP wants to use a dynamic model in which he uses the label for each new day to retrain the model and predict further. Initially, it was not clear that whether he wants to use the predicted output for each new day or the correct label for each new day. After reading the comments, it became clear that he wants to use the correct labels corresponding to each new day.
- Had it been the other way round, the problem with using the predicted output for `t`th day to predict the output for `t+1`th was that, it takes into account the error associated with the prediction for `t`th day. And hence, that addition of one extra data-point to our already existing `t-1` training data-points might or might-not have been helpful depending upon the accuracy of the model.
- Now coming to the part that the OP actually wants to ask. So, adding the correct label for each day and retraining the model will definitely improve it's accuracy to some extent. However, if `t-1` is large (greater than say minimum 50 data-points as discussed in the beginning of [Scikit-Learn's Flow Chart](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html)), then, the contribution by the labelled data from `t`th day won't make much difference in the accuracy as it is just one extra training data-point out of `n`.
- That is, it would be a better idea to wait for k more days, and then re-train the model using `t-1+k` correctly labelled data-points.
- So, to summarize, the best way to check the accuracy of the present model is, since we have the correct labels for all of these `t-1` data-points, randomly divide the `t-1` data-points into 60% training data-points, 20% testing data-points and 20% cross-validation data-points. And then, these randomly selected data-points can be permuted further among each other in `5C2` ways for [K-fold Cross Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).
- Now comes the question is how large the k should be? That is, how long should we wait before retraining the model? The answer to this question is very subjective and depends upon certain requirements:

  - For example, let's say the present accuracy of the model is not very good, so in such case, it would be a better idea to frequently retrain the model until it starts meeting a decided threshold. That is, k can be small in such cases.
  - Another good way to decide the value of k is by observing the patterns between feature-vectors of different days. If the feature-vectors significantly change according to seasons, then, k can be as large as 2-3 months. If the feature-vectors drastically change every week, then, k can be 7 days and so on.
- The point is that each retraining step should add some significant value to the model and it's accuracy. Retraining every day might not fulfill that purpose. In the end, the idea is to maintain a fine balance between **"2-3 hrs retraining & prediction cost"** and **"model-accuracy after each retrain"**.

Comment: apologies for the unclear question.. and i think you have hit the main issue spot on.. ie how to choose k, or how long to wait before retraining the model.. from my empirical observations i have not been able to convince myself for a chosen period as the feature vectors do not hold any pattern.. sometimes they look consistent-ish for a week, sometimes a month, sometimes it changes drastically daily.. hence i thought of using k = 1day, but that brought about the retraining cost in terms of the time factor..

Comment: so in a nutshell, i need to convince myself of a value for k (as you have defined it) and this need not be a purely objective exercise.. am i correct in understanding your reply?

Comment: Yes, k=1 works perfectly well if you are Okay with retraining everyday. It has to be decided on the basis of a convenience threshold. Anyways, may I know what are the feature variables that you are taking corresponding to each day? This might help in the pattern analysis as suggested in the main body of the answer.

Comment: Also, let's not forget the "adding significant value to the accuracy of the model" part.
i) What is the accuracy of the model when you divide your (t-1)-day-data into 60:20:20?
ii) By what amount this accuracy changes when you do the same for (t)-day-data?
iii) By what amount this accuracy changes when you do the same for (t-1+k)-day-data for k = {10, 20, 30....}
If you see a significant jump in the accuracy after taking a certain value of k, then that is value which you are looking for.

Comment: i am using k-fold validation on my data, and ran a lot of tests to try and figure out the optimum n on historical data, and again no discernable pattern that holds true. i have decided to go with @bogatron suggestion to retrain on an incorrect prediction, for the time being.. Thank you so much for your suggestions!